# How to link math.h library in geany?

Tags: c, linux, geany

SO I startedd coding with geany but every time i use the library math.h 
and then use somthing like pow or powf it marks me an error.

I do realize that when compiling i have to use -lm in the terminal but is there a  way to make it so that geany will automatically use -lm when compiling in geany?

Thank you! c:

Comment: What is the error? compiling error or link error?

Comment: What type of compiling error? Usually there is an error code for each situation. Please give us the explicit message

Comment: /tmp/cc1CKNqM.o: In function `main':
fig04_06.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `powf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit statusv
Sorry im quite new to geany and linux so i didnt know

Comment: Add -lm option to the end of gcc command line in the Build -> Set Build Commands menu.

Comment: That fixed it! :o
Thank you very much ^.^

Comment: @Ari0nhh Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: you stated it was a compile time error not a linker error.  adding -lm is linker time.  For compile time, the following line needs to be in the code, near the top of the file: #include <math.h>

Answer (score 1):

Add `-lm` to compiler command configuration done under Build->Set Build Commands. you could also build a a makefile your file.

Answer (score 1):

must include " **#include <math.h>**"  then after saving file, go to their file location -

In geany---------------------------

go to the terminal-

then, go to the file location like-

```
cd /home/.....your_file_location
```

then link math.h file in your c/c++ executable like this one-

```
gcc file.c -lm
```

[image]

now,

this file executes in geany editor without error-

> build > execute

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the math.h to your program since it is a header file. But the functions defined in math.h are implemented in the libm.a.

You should add `-lm` to your compiler call to avoid this *link error*.