# How to get Geany to link with the math library in C?

Tags: c, geany, math.h

I'm using the Linux Mint distribution, and writing a program in C. However, I'm having trouble with the compilation part. Specifically, none of the math.h functions seem to work (like sqrt() or pow()).

I know that if I were compiling through the terminal I would have to link it myself by adding the -lm part at the end of the command. But is there a way to do it through Geany? Or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link math.h library in geany?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183812/how-to-link-math-h-library-in-geany)

Answer (score 1):

under the geany 'build' menu item is the selection: `Set Build Commands`

after clicking `build` then `Set Build Commands` the `Set Build Commands` window opens.

under the first column is `label` under that is `Compile` to the right of `Compile` is a text box where you type the compile command.

ON my system, the contents of the compile text box is:

```
gcc -ggdb  -Wall -Wextra  -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes  -c "%f"  -I.
```

the next line down is labeled `Build` to the right of the `Build` is a text box where you type the link command.

On my system, the contents of the build text box is:

```
gcc -ggdb  -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -pedantic -o "%e" "%f"   -lpthread -lm
```

(actual contents will vary for special needs)

Notice, at the END of the `Build` text box are the library items to be included.   Amongst those libraries is the `libm.so` (which is written without the `lib` and without the `so`.)  I.E. `-lm`

That is all that is needed to compile and link 'many/most' programs.

Note: the parameter `-ggdb` is to have the compile and link steps include all the debug information for the `gdb` debugger